# Search in php by combine 2 unordered lists

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have an unordered list which somebody can search for images which belongs in current category. i have this code in a while loop:

```
<li><a class="ct" href="account.php?view_templates&category=<?php echo $category['id']; ?>"><?php echo $category['name']; ?></a></li>
```

Also i have an unordered list which somebody can search for images which belongs in a current size.I have used jquery to get the li value and send it via ajax to php file to give me the results.

```
<li value="728x90"><a href="#">728x90</a></li>
```

I get the results using this code to my php file:

```
if(isset($_POST['size'])){
  $size = $_POST['size'];
  $gs = $db->query("SELECT * FROM images WHERE size = '$size'");
  while($images = $gs->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    //I store the images here
  }
}
```

The problem is that when somebody has selected a category and after that he trying to select a size, then as result i have only the size but no the current category. The wished result is to search the sizes but in the specific selected category..not to all categories.. how can i do that? Thanks..

Comment: If it isn't as simple as adding `AND category = '$category'` to your sql query, you need to elaborate your problem a bit more.

Comment: you are getting size from form POST and category from url???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Database :** postgresql

**Try to make your query in parts.**

```
$size = $_POST['size'];
$category = $_POST['category'];

if(isset($size)){
  $size = "AND size = $size";
}
if(isset($category)){
  $category = "AND category = $category";
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM images WHERE true $size $category";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$gs = $db->query("SELECT * FROM images WHERE size LIKE '%". $size ."%'");
```